# IIS Manager opens maximized and the Restore Down button minimizes the window; the window cannot be made smaller

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors, size

I have two monitors on a Windows 10 x64 system. IIS Manager (IIS 10) opens maximized in the left monitor and it cannot be made smaller or moved to the other monitor. Clicking the "Restore Down" button minimizes the window. Is this a known problem and is there  a fix for it?  I have tablet mode disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I have not heard of such a problem.

It might be due to the fact that
IIS Manager will not let you reduce its window below a certain size.

The screen of your tablet might be too small for it not to take up
the entire screen.

If you suspect Windows corruption, run
[Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html)
and
[sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).
Ensure also that Windows 10 is fully updated.